# laravel default controller method without explicit routing?

Tags: php, laravel

Does laravel have a default method it renders within a controller, like the `index` method in codeigniter?

Right now I have a controller called `TestController`, and within it a method like so:

```
public function index()
{
    echo 'string';
}
```

What I would like to happen is: when I navigate to mysite.com/public/test I would like the index method to be rendered by default ( or whatever is the equivalent of `index` in laravel).

Right now I can do this only if I place the following in the `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

So, is it possible for this to happen automatically in laravel, or do I have to make specific routes for **each and every controller and method**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has **implicit controllers** functionality. which will allow one to define methods with index which will be called with root URI.

Refer documentation at : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers

Comment: I see it now. Still I need to write a line for each controller, which is ridiculous IMO.

Comment: please post the answer, then link as a reference. this page may be removed, at that time, this answer is a useless one.